# How can I insert latex symbols into a matlab plot?

Tags: plot, matlab

I have a figure in Matlab with axes that I would like to label with latex symbols like `$\delta$` on the x axis and `$\epsilon$` on the y axis.  How can I place these LaTeX notations into the axis labels?

Comment: although [tex and latex interpreter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/adding-text-annotations-to-graphs.html?searchHighlight=tex+latex+interpreter#f0-28104) in matlab are not proper. try these `xlabel('Symbol $\delta$','interpreter','latex');` and `ylabel('Symbol $\epsilon$','interpreter','latex');`. see [xlabel doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlabel.html). and [What is the best way to include Matlab graphics?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3995/15717)

Comment: If you're planning to export your figure for use in a LaTeX document, take a look at http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz.

Comment: Indeed, you can export matlab figures as tikz figures and add LaTeX expressions later.

Answer (score 17):

when plotting in Matlab, set the text interpreter to be latex:

```
Figure1=figure(1);clf;
set(Figure1,'defaulttextinterpreter','latex');
plot(...);
xlabel('$\delta$');
ylabel('$\epsilon$');
```

Comment: set(0,'DefaultTextInterpreter', 'latex')