# Use Matlab 2014b figures (via Inkscape) in pdfTeX

Tags: fonts, pdftex, matlab, matlab2tikz, inkscape

I know there are many threads related to this topic, but I still could not find a satisfying solution.

**Summary**
Matlab 2014b figures -> export as .eps or .svg -> load into Inkscape (*problem is in here: text is not recognized*) -> use Inkscpe to save as .pdf_tex -> use in scrreprt  document (pdfTeX)

---

**The goal:**
I want to use different Matlab 2014b plots in a scientific paper. Within those plot I want to use the same LaTeX font as it is used in my scrreprt document.

**The problem:**
When I export or print the Matlab figures as .eps or .svg (possible in 2014b) it is not possible to use the document font (type and size) or access the text (labels, axisticks) Inkscape.

**What I've done so far:**
I used [matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz). This lets me access the plot with the "correct" font. **But** it does not create the results I want to have. [This thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3995/what-is-the-best-way-to-include-matlab-graphics) mentions a related problem.

I greated some figures in Inkscape (.svg) and used the export method which provides .pdf_tex files. Then I used \input to include them into the to the document. This works very well ("correct font and nice quality"), so I want to use this method, but in the first place I need to print/export the figures in a way that lets Inkscape read the text as text and notas pixels in a picture.

**What is definitely not desired**
Setting the Matlab figure 'Interpreter' to 'Latex' looks nice in the figure, but is useless when including it into a latex document

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Due to a comment, I also posted the question [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/48986/use-matlab-2014b-figures-via-inkscape-in-pdftex).

Comment: Have you considered exporting only the data (.csv or something), read this data with tikz and create a nice plot from within latex (tikz)?

Comment: I've done some pretty complicated pictures with `matlab2tikz`. What's the problem in your case?

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. The problem is, that I always have to tweak the beginning of the x-axis, because the plotted line is different in tikz. Another problem is, that tikz always draws the box around the legend, what has to be removed manually. @Steffen I did not consider yet. But since I need many figures, I am scared of doing it manually, plus I am really new to tikz

Comment: pgfplots can have global settings that can be set once and you would have them applied to all plots in your document. See Section 4.3.7 Importing graphics in the pgfplots document.

Comment: The problem of Inkscape not recognizing the text in a Matlab-generated file is, I fear, completely off-topic for this site.

Comment: Thank you @percusse for your hint. I could not find a way to apply something like `legend style={..., draw=none}` to all the figures, where tikz is used. The referened section says, that the axis have to be created manually for every figure. So this would be relapse-level, but not my first choise. @Torjorn T. maybe you are right, but I made good experiences with the answers in this forum.

Comment: OT questions do get answers sometimes, but I'm still considering voting to close. If you switched focus from the Inkscape problem (which would fit better on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ I think, possibly [so]) to the `pgfplots` problem, then it would be fine. (I'm not trying to be mean, but this is, in my opinion, the wrong place.)

Comment: Hi. What I've found when importing figures from matlab to inkscape is that you need to replace the font. There are extensions for this: https://code.google.com/p/inkscape-replace-font/ or it should also be possible to do this with find and replace.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use inkscape inbetween the generation and import into the document? When i create plots for papers, i always do all of the additions to the plots programatically, so that if the data changes, it's easy to update the figures, and i've never found anything i was unable to add into the script which generates the graphs...

Answer (score 2):

If anybody in the future encounters the same problem, please read this:

After a lot of trial, I came to the conclusion, that it is probably the best to use `matlab2tikz` or `pgfplots`.

The [link](https://code.google.com/p/inkscape-replace-font/) that @Dolphin posted in his comment leads to a handy extension of Inkscape, which fulfills its purpose. All the text in the Matlab figures got recognized. The problem is the export from Inkscape later on. You could use .eps or even the .pdf export, which works as in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MK3cWRA5eLQ). The problem is, that you have to adjust all the axess ticks, labels and legend entries manually. This is OK for figures with less text, but inappropriate for scientific figures with lots of data (numbers and legends).

P.S.: I don't know how to close the thread, since I created it with a guest account (Now I am writing form my own Stack Exchange account, which has the same Name.). If any Admin reads this, you may want to mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: You can ask an administrator to merge your two accounts ...

Comment: You'll need to contact the Staff Exchange staff to merge your accounts: see the [Contact page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/contact).

Answer (score 0):

Another much easier solution is: don't use LaTeX in Matlab 2014b to label your axis. For example, you cannot have any thing like `x_1^*`. If you use only plain text in Matlab, then when you save the file to SVG, the text will be kept. You can then edit the `.pdf_tex` file generated by Inkscape to show the correct label. This is of course due to the bug of the `figure-to-svg` engine in Matlab 2014b. It simply cannot recognize LaTeX as text.