# Inlining circuit symbols

Tags: formatting, circuitikz

in a prevois question i asked if there was a good way to display electronics symbols in TeX, i was pointed towards circuitikz (which is awsome), but is there a way to inline a symbol in text?

eg.

bla bla bla {symbols} blaa blab bla

Comment: What kind of symbol are you talking about?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe in this case it's easier to use the `circuits.ee.IEC` library in `TikZ` instead of `circuitikz`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}

% Define a command for drawing dipole symbols with a bit of wire on either end
\newcommand\esymbol[1]{\tikz[circuit ee IEC] \draw (0,0) -- (.1,0) node [#1,anchor=west,name=s] {} (s.east) -- +(.1,0);}

This is a diode \esymbol{diode} and this is a resistor \esymbol{resistor}

\end{document}
```

[image: Inline circuit symbols]

---

**Edit:** The following is merged from another answer I wrote:

Similar approach with `circuitikz`, but the spacing is quite bad:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\ctikzset{bipoles/length=.6cm}
\newcommand\esymbol[1]{\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to [#1] (1,0); \end{circuitikz}}

This is a diode \esymbol{diode} and this is a resistor \esymbol{generic}

\end{document}
```

[image: inline circuit symbols with circuitikz]

Comment: Perhaps you'd consider merging both your answers into one?

Comment: @Martin  
Is that the preferred thing to do? I figured that, since one method is (in my opinion) superior to the other (which is also reflected by the votes), it would make sense to keep them as separate answers. I'm glad to merge them if that's what's expected, though.

Comment: There are different schools of thought whether this is preferred or not.. but personally I like posts that summarize and contrast different solutions -- even more so when you have written both answers yourself. This is what makes (for me) a good and informative answer that one is happy to upvote, even if not all solutions are equally good. You don't *have* to merge them, of course -- it's your call.

Comment: @Martin Fair point. I have merged the answers and deleted the second one. There's a similar situation on [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9484/using-tikz-and-psfrag), where I also wrote two answers. I'll keep those separate, as there have been comments added to both, but I'll keep your advice in mind in the future.