# How could I include svg directly into LaTeX?

Tags: svg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to include SVG diagrams in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/how-to-include-svg-diagrams-in-latex)

Is there a way to include svg figures directly into LaTeX?
This is my current way to include eps file:

```
\clearpage    
\begin{figure*}     
\psfig{figure=187947.fig.001.eps}    
\caption{} \label{fig:1}    
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Looks like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/how-to-include-svg-diagrams-in-latex to me

Comment: No, my question has no relation to a text problem,I want to include svg file directly into latex without intermediate conversion (even if pdf)  , Now I am using these lines to include my eps file(converted from svg) into latex:  
`\clearpage
\begin{figure*}
\psfig{figure=187947.fig.001.eps}
\caption{} \label{fig:1}
\end{figure*}`

Comment: Please note that [tag:latex3] is not an appropriate tag for this question.

Comment: see [Martin Heller's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2106/1410) in the question Joseph linked to.

Comment: You can't include SVG in LaTeX without conversion. It's possible to make an automatic conversion when using pdflatex, but this is operating system dependent.

Comment: could you please explain how could this automatic conversion be done? cause I am new in using Latex.

Comment: @hala_zzz Not until you don't explain what operating system you're using. I advise you to read an up-to-date guide: the `\psfig` command has been obsolete from many years.

Comment: @egreg I am using win7 enterprise