# Inserting SVG markup directly in LaTeX

Tags: technical-drawing, svg

Is there any package that let inserting SVG markups directly in LaTeX and get result image like:

```
\begin{svg}[version="1.1"]
  <polygon points="100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
\end{svg}
```

Comment: As detailed in [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/how-to-include-svg-diagrams-in-latex](How to include SVG diagrams in LaTeX?), the nearest I think you'll get is using TikZ and an appropriate `\path`, but this will not work for arbirtary SVG.

Comment: Do you want to include a listing of `svg` code, or do you wan to "run" the `svg` code and include the resulting picture?

Comment: @JLDiaz Second one. I want include result picture. Perhaps a package can map SVG code internally to TikZ.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to do it in LaTeX, but in ConTeXt you can use the `filter` module to run a converter, for example inkscape and include the output. Here is an example of this:

```
\usemodule
  [filter,ipsum]

\define[1]\readSVGfile
  {\externalfigure[#1]}

\defineexternalfilter
  [SVG]
  [filtercommand={inkscape                   \space
      --without-gui                          \space
      --export-ignore-filters                \space
      --export-pdf=\externalfilteroutputfile \space
      --file=\externalfilterinputfile        \space
    },
    readcommand=\readSVGfile,
    output=\externalfilterbasefile.svg]

\starttext

\startSVG
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="88" width="74">
      <polygon points="100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180" style="fill:lime;   
      stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
  </svg>
\stopSVG

\ipsum
\stoptext
```

The output:

[image: result]

Of course, you need to have inkscape installed for the conversion.