# include svg images with the svg package

Tags: graphics, svg

I'm trying to use the `svg` package for inserting svg images in my latex file, as suggested in other questions. But now I ran into a problem:

For example I have a image `figure1.svg`, if I write

```
\includesvg{figure1}
```

it will give an error says

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: File `figure1.pdf_tex' not found.
```

But if I write

```
\includesvg{figure1.svg}
```

it will give another error says

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .svg.
```

How can I fix this problem? I'll prefer not having to convert all my `svg` files to `pdf_tex` files with some external program.

---

### Update

My LaTeX environment is latest the TeXLive 2013 on Windows 7. A MWE code would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includesvg{figure1.svg}
  \caption{svg image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just tried it using a simple SVG. I had all prerequisites: adding the `--shell-escape` option to `pdflatex` and installing `ImageMagick`. To me it seems as if the package is a bit buggy.

Comment: I spite of your last sentence, I suggest change all `\includesvg{..}`  by  `\includegraphics{...}` without any extension and (1) import the latex document with Lyx to allow an automatic conversion with `rsvg-convert` or (2) work directly with pdf files that still can be edited with Inkscape. For many files is less painfull the command line  (`inkscape -f file.svg -A file.pdf`).

Comment: May be useful: [How to include SVG diagrams in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74693)

Comment: Had this same error using XeLaTeX with Texmaker on GNU/Linux where `\includesvg{image}`  or `\includesvg{image.svg}` just wouldn't work. Had to do `\includegraphics{image}` and then it magically started working.

Comment: Convert to PNG. Then, `\includegraphics{}`. You're welcome.

Comment: @pushpen.paul I'd rather convert it to a pdf to keep the vector graphics.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The problem is that you have given a file extension: you should not do this (indeed this seems clear in the [`svg` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/svg). For me, the short demo

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{amsmath} % you need amsmath as the demo includes a use of \eqref
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includesvg{image}
  \caption{svg image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

using the [demonstration file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/svg-inkscape/image.svg) used by the package works fine.

Note that for this to work:

- You need Inkscape on your path ([why?](https://inkscape.org/forums/questions/during-installation-what-does-add-to-system-path-mean/)) ([schtandard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/48973/schtandard) pointed to [this step-by-step](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523685/48973) of the setup)
- You need to compile your `.tex` file to *PDF* with the `--shell-escape` option enabled

Comment: Getting this to work on Windows is OK, but on my Mac seems tricky. That's likely an Inkscape/Mac issue, so not relevant here!

Comment: Calling `svg` as `\usepackage[inkscape={/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape -z -C}]{svg}` seems to solve the issue on Mac OS X (assuming Inkscape has been installed with the `.dmg` file.

Comment: @egreg I'd tried that and also adding Inkscape to `/etc/paths`: in both cases I get some errors at the Inkscape end, presumably due to which support items I have set up (and which it expects to be present).

Comment: I'll probably remove the version I installed with the `.dmg` and try with the one provided by Homebrew, which should work out of the box with `svg`.

Comment: Somehow it does not work for me, when I remove the `.svg` extension, I got the error `File not found`.

Comment: @LWZ Did you install Inkscape and add it to your path? If so, does `inkscape` work at the Command Prompt? Do you get any other errors in the log?

Comment: @JosephWright Sorry! Did not see the last sentence in your answer! No I do not have `inkscape` in my path. I thought `inkscape` is just a program to generate svg files externally.

Comment: @LWZ No, what actually happens is that the `svg` package uses Inkscape to convert to PDF on-the-fly. You have to have Inkscape available for this to work.

Comment: I had problems when the image was located in different folder e.g. `../images/image2`. The pdfs are created on the fly in this directory, but then tex tries to include the pdfs from the previous directory.

Comment: Adding to this: I can get the MWE to work (from @Joseph Wright) to work when I'm using LateX to typeset, but when I switch to XeLaTeX it fails with the following: ./Untitled.tex:8: Undefined control sequence.
\@includesvg ...extracttrue \fi \ifnum \pdfstrcmp 
                                                  {\pdffilemoddate {\SVG@in@...
l.8   \includesvg{image}

Comment: Do you have to include the extension `.svg` to the `\includesvg` command?

Comment: Anyway making it work without Inkscape?

Comment: @JosephWright what is meant by this `You need Inkscape on your path`. Path that we give while installing inkspacke, should be of .tex file?

Comment: @Infinity On the search path that your OS uses to find executables.

Comment: @JosephWright in system variables?

Comment: @Infinity: In $PATH.

Comment: This part doesn't really make sense: "The problem is that you have given a file extension:". How are you supposed to specify the image without a file extension? What if there are 2 images with the same basename but different extension...?

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem.

I found a simple way to deal with it.

- Just open the svg file by Inkscape.
- Save as the .pdf format
- On the next pop up window:

  - Embed Fonts
  - Use exported object's size
  - Margin 0.1
- click ok

Next the generated pdf file will be imported by latex easily as same as png or eps.

---

But some times inkscape does not read the svg file properly and some mistakes are occurred. In this case the solution which works for me is:

- generate a pdf version of figure by your used designer software
- include the pdf file in latex
- use trim for cropping the figure in latex

for example:

```
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth, trim={1cm 3cm 1cm 8cm},clip]{Fig.pdf}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is not really an answer as you do not include the svg (that's what's asked for).

Comment: @TeXnician You are very stringent. Generally I like this, but in this case … You are absolutely right: It's not an answer to the asked question but an alternative way to avoid the problem.

Comment: It's a relevant answer since using the svg package is using inkscape and will create a .pdf in the root directory anyway. BTW inkscape can do this in one command if someone wish to integrate it in a script or whatever

Answer (score 1):

*While this may not be a valuable option for some users, it may be worth it for some:*

Online SVG to PDF converters.

Here you may find [Google search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=online%20svg%20to%20pdf%20converter).

After this one may follow the usual strategies for embedding PDF files into LaTeX,

(as described for example in the answer above).

Hope this helps some users. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and just wanted to share the trivial solution which worked for me. I am using overleaf by the way.

I had to remove one layer from my folder structure.

---

This did not work:

```
+-- data
|   +-- img
|       +-- file.svg
+--TeX
|  +-- Sections
|  |   +-- 01_Section.tex
|  +-- main.tex
|  +-- ...
```

Removing "TeX" layer solved the porblem:

```
+-- data
|   +-- img
|       +-- file.svg
+-- Sections
|   +-- 01_Section.tex
+-- main.tex
+-- ...
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you explain, why the second folder structure works?

Comment: I think, it's about forgetting "../" in the file path. With the first folder structure, it is `../data/img/file.svg`, where as in the second, it is `data/img/file.svg`.