# How to use import package to keep relative path references in subfiles and at the same time use svg?

Tags: svg, import

I have the following directory structure:

```
main.tex
chapter/
    chapter1.tex
    img/
        image.svg
```

This is the content of `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}
\import{chapter/}{chapter1}
\end{document}
```

This is `chapter/chapter1.tex`:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includesvg[width=0.7\textwidth, svgpath = img/]{image}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```

How to use import package to keep relative path references in subfiles and at the same time use svg files?

If I use the svg in a main file and not in a subfile, it's generated correctly.

Comment: Does `svg` work normally on your system? Did you ever try it without `\import` or `svgpath`? Consider [egreg's comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122871/include-svg-images-with-the-svg-package#comment292628_129854)

Comment: Yes, as I said at the end, this works properly without import. Without svgpath attribute it won't work.

Comment: Oops, missed that. It looks like `svg` package **does** know  the correct path and did try it. You can prove/disprove it by testing any other extensions (`.png`/`.jpg`/etc). Turns out this package reports poor error messages so I cannot tell where things go wrong. A stupid fix may be adding the current directory in `\Ginput@path` to `svgpath` by hand.

Comment: How can I add `\Ginput@path` to `svgpath`? Can you give an example? I've tried, but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
\makeatletter
  \svgpath{{\input@path/img/}}
\makeatother
```

to the start of `chapter1.tex` works.