# Inkscape and --shell-escape with TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, svg

My purpose is to show `fig1.svg` in latex. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Matlab}
\lstset{tabsize=2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includesvg[width=140mm]{fig1}
\caption{Previous saturated output \label{overflow}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I got two error:

```
File `./fig1' not found. \includesvg[width=140mm]{fig1}
File `fig1.pdf_tex' not found. \includesvg[width=140mm]{fig1}
```

I followed this [URL](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122871/include-svg-images-with-the-svg-package) and everything is right except for

> You need Inkscape on your path
>
> You need to run the file with the --shell-escape option enabled

I use texstudio in ubuntu. So should I copy the .deb application on this path?!!!  running which file with `--shell-escape`?

```
$ texstudio --shell-escap
```

still is the same!

Comment: Open a terminal, go to the directory of the .tex file and run `pdflatex --shell-escape name_of_tex_file` (I'm not sure that you can make this from `texstudio`). Provided you have Inkscape installed, it should be in your path (that only means that Inkscape's executable file is in a place where the system can find it, e.g. in /usr/bin/), so I don't think that should be a problem.

Comment: In texstudio: go to `Options->Configure texstudio`. Click on `Commands`. Add -shell-escape flag to `pdflatex`: `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex`

Answer (score 1):

A thing you should consider, apart from having the flag `-shell-escape` before the `%.tex` part, is to have TexStudio installed using `apt-get`, and not `flatpak`. If the latter, then the program will not be run at the environment where inkscape is installed. The same holds for inkscape.