# Texstudio and Inkscape-- error "Inkscape not Installed" but definitely in $PATH and ~.bashrc

Tags: texstudio, paths, inkscape

Suggestions at [TexStudio and Inkscape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233511/inkscape-and-shell-escape-with-texstudio) were followed as my problem also involves the use of `--shell-escape`. No improvement using methods suggested there. Here is my situation:

I am attempting to use TeXstudio to compile documents requiring access to Inkscape and also the use of `--shell-escape`. Despite having installed both TeXstudio and Inkscape from `apt get install` (compliant with answer given in noted URL), TeXstudio insists it cannot find Inkscape. I have put the paths to Inkscape in my `.bashrc` file and `echo $PATH`definitely shows Inkscape. Moreover, Inkscape does appear in the GUI of Linux Mint. Besides the error message

```
Class pagelayout Error: Inkscape not installed. Shadow not created.
```

I also get this error *regardless of whether Inkscape is called, or not:*

```
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
```

Hopefully, the 2nd error re: $TERM will be a useful diagnostic.

Comment: is inkscape in the path of the shell that lauched texstudio? (eg if you start it from a root desktop but set the path in your personal bashrc) My advice would be to check it works from the commandlie first, then worry about the editor

Comment: Hello David--any idea of the name of the shell that launches texstudio? I cannot find any obvious candidates. Any idea of what $TERM is?

Comment: not a name but depending how things are ser up your desktop may not see .basrc settings  you may need .bash_profile or similar and log out and  reboot

Comment: David: Thanks, I looked for other 'bash' files and appended one of them, but that didn't have any +ve effect. Also, following the suggestion at [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233511/inkscape-and-shell-escape-with-texstudio), I checked both my TexStudio and Inkscape installations and neither of these were installed using Flatpack. I have looked at all the locations in the Path for Inkscape, and to the best of my knowledge there is only one Inkscape installation.