# svg package failing to find svg files

Tags: graphics, mac, svg

I am trying to get the svg package working on an OSX system. If I use inkscape to save the *.svg files as *.pdf and *.pdf_tex, then the sample file from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122871/include-svg-images-with-the-svg-package)  works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includesvg{example}
  \caption{svg image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But no matter what I try, the package will not create the pdf and pdf_tex files automatically. Instead I get an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `./example' not found.
```

I have added inkscape to the PATH. I've added the `--shell-escape` option to the latex command... I'm at a loss.

Comment: If the conversion is not successful, the necessary files won't be found. Try the manual conversion `inkscape -z -C -f./example.svg -A./example.pdf --export-latex` which may give some hints about what's going wrong.

Comment: Did you install it via dmg? You can check the installation dir with `which inkscape`. If this returns no answers, the problem is, that LaTeX can't find `inkscape` at all.

Comment: @egreg The command line does not work. `** (inkscape-bin:821): WARNING **: Can't open file: example.svg (doesn't exist)`. This looks to be related to a Mac python [issue with directories](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/MacOS_X). However, I've tried every combination on that webpage and nothing works.

Comment: @Rico I installed via dmg, which I got from the website a few days ago. `which inkscape` gives `/usr/local/bin/inkscape`. Even if I run the command using the full path - I have the same issue.

Comment: Maybe you could provide a screenshot of your folder structure. Could make it easier to figure out what is going wrong

Comment: Inkscape lives in  `/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape` (this is the script which runs inkscape). I've got the svg example in `/Users/weymouth/Downloads/svg`.

Comment: I cannot understand why this error message appears: ! LaTeX Error: File `./example' not found. Latex would call Inkscape if the SVG source file is changed. Now if there is something wrong with calling Inkscape, Latex would use the old "./example" files. So where are those files. Still there or disappeared?

Answer (score 5):

This is a macOS-specific issue.

The `inkscape` shell script which invokes the main inkscape binary has to change directory to the inkscape installation directory, which is why it fails finding the SVG files in the current working directory.

See this explanatory comment on line 30 of the inkscape script, `/usr/local/bin/inkscape` on my macOS:

```
# Due to changes after 0.48, we have to change working directory in the script named 'inkscape':
# recursive calls to inkscape from python-based extensions otherwise cause the app to hang or
# fail (for python-based extensions, inkscape changes the working directory to the 
# script's directory, and inkscape launched by python script thus can't find resources
# like the now essential 'units.xml' in INKSCAPE_UIDIR relative to the working directory).
cd "$BASE" || exit 1
```

That's a smoking gun if I've ever seen one. :)

You can try commenting out the `cd "$BASE" || exit 1` line, and the conversion should still work for simple SVGs. This is what I am currently doing.

Alternatively, one would have to modify `svg` LaTeX package to invoke inkscape with full input and output pathnames instead of relative. Another option would be to modify the `inkscape` shell script to expand relative paths to absolute.

Comment: I'll try this out and hopefully give you a (long overdue) checkmark.

Answer (score 3):

Check that inkscape is in your `PATH` environment variable.

Test this by opening up your command terminal window and typing `inkscape --version` (do *not* do this in the directory you installed inkscape; we want to see if your environment can find the program from an arbitrary location, like your home directory)

If it returns with a version, then this is not your problem (sorry).

However, If it responds with any form of error, then the svg package won't be able to call inkscape to convert the file. For directions on adding inkscape to your `PATH`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7703041/6146369) ([here](http://m.windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path) for Windows).

Good luck!

Comment: The poster already states the program is the PATH and shows an error message from the Inkscape saying it can't find the svg file.

Comment: Besides, the OP is on Mac OS X.

Comment: I've had similar errors on Linux and windows where the error shown was "cannot find file" when it was actually a path issue. So just suggesting this as a  troubleshooting step to double check that it was added to PATH properly by running from console. (I've messed that up before).  I'll amend the answer to add in editing path for Mac, missed that in the Q. Txs.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your command-line call to put --shell-escape first:

`pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode example.tex`

After having the \includesvg work and not work in Windows and Linux (ubuntu), and having this exact problem sometimes, but not others (however, after it stopped working, it seemed really hard to get it to compile again), I found that putting the --shell-escape option FIRST in the command line seems to make the pdflatex call work **every** time.

I hope this helps other people, I've been caught by this over and over again with no real rhyme or reason for why the pdflatex call starts failing.

Good luck! Let me know if this works for anyone else out there.

Answer (score 2):

#### Linux & Snap problem

If you're on Linux and installed inkscape via snap store the svg file cannot be opened due to permission issues with snaps sandbox.

You can confirm this by right clicking on a file -> open with -> inkscape. Nothing will happen.

#### How to fix

Open your terminal and type:
`which inkscape`
This should return `/snap/bin/inkscape`
type to uninstall inkscape from snap:`sudo snap remove inkscape`
Type to install via ppa:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install inkscape
```

type to confirm inkscape was installed: `which inkscape`
This should return `/usr/bin/inkscape`

This is the currently opened issue: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/3649
Maybe someone can find a solution by modifying the snap permissions?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was the `--clean` option.  I figured this out by selected pdflatex in TeXWorks and it suddenly built.  Taking out options one by one helped me get to the bottom of this.  Hope this helps someone (probably future me in six months).

Comment: maybe you should mention that you are using latexmk, otherwise this answer might not make sense