# passing the extension to \includesvg - damned if you do, damned if you don't

Tags: graphics, external-files, paths, svg, package-options

I'm trying to use the `svg` package, for some svg files I have in a `graphics/` subdirectory. My includegraphics command used to be:

```
\includegraphics{graphics/foo.png}
```

Now, if I write:

```
\includesvg{graphics/foo.svg}
```

I get [this issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122871/include-svg-images-with-the-svg-package): The package needs you *not* to specify the file extension. But if I write

```
\includesvg{graphics/foo}
```

I get:

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: File `./graphics/foo' not found.
> ```

and even if I set the path and write:

```
\includesvg[svgpath=./graphics/]{foo}
```

I still get:

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: File `./graphics/foo' not found.
> ```

Finally, the svg package documentation says:

> The path to the svg can be specified using the svgpath option, where the path must terminate in a /.

So that last attempt should have gotten me there. But just to be on the safe side, I tried:

```
\includesvg[svgpath=./graphics/.]{foo}
```

and still got

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: File `./graphics/.foo' not found.
> ```

What should I do then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works, provided you launch `pdflatex` with the `-shell-escape` option and you have `inkscape` on your system. This will call the (slow) conversion from SVG to PDF, with an accompanying TeX file. Later runs don't need the conversion, so they also work without the `-shell-escape` option.

So, if the file is `test.tex` you need

```
pdflatex -shell-escape test
```

(adjust for the method you run LaTeX on your system).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

\includesvg[svgpath=./graphics/]{Steps}

\end{document}
```

The SVG file has been taken from https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/

[image]

Comment: Can I get latexmk to use `-shell-escape`?

Comment: @einpoklum The manual of `latexmk` describes how to do it

Comment: Did you get this to work with latexmk? I'm using the command `latexmk -shell-escape mydocument`, and getting the same errors as you were getting (`! LaTeX Error: File <filename> not found`).

Comment: @FilipS.: Sorry for missing your question... as you can tell from my answer below, I went a different way. I'll assume this works.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since `svg` needs inkscape anyway, you can just circumvent the issue altogether and perform the conversion yourself:

```
inkscape -z --export-pdf=foo.pdf foo.svg
```

to convert the file once and for all (assuming it doesn't change repeatedly). To automate that over all files in the current directory, try:

```
ls *.svg | while read f; do inkscape -z --export-pdf="${f/\.svg/.pdf}" "$f"; done
```

(but make sure your filenames don't contain .svg twice, otherwise you'd need something more involved.)