# How to draw the neighbourhood of an open set?

Tags: draw

I would like to be able to draw a pretty general open set (not just a ball) and to draw some neighbourhoods of it (at different distances), as in the following picture:

[image: Neighbourhood of an open set]

Comment: This answer can be adpted to your situation https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/580768/140722