# Not supported by viewer issue when including eps file converted from svg format

Tags: graphics, eps, svg

I'm using TeXstudio 2.11.2 to compile my document.

The document class i'm using is.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,hidelinks,openright]{report}
```

I want to include an `.eps` image to my document. This image has been wrongly converted from this `.svg` file ([ufile.io/r4ift](http://ufile.io/r4ift)), using this online tool converter (https://cloudconvert.com/svg-to-eps).

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{my_eps_image}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

When I visualize the image, the wrongly converted `.svg` is shown as @JosephWright has detected. This is then not a Latex error.

[image: error]

How can I fix it and convert correctly the `.svg` image? Or, is it simpler to include directly the initial `.svg` image.

---

Edit with a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,hidelinks,openright]{report}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=1]{my_eps_image}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What viewer are you using, and are you using a DVI or PDF-based workflow (`latex` or `pdflatex`)?

Comment: @JosephWright I'm using Adobe Acrobat Reader (I suppose that the viewer integrated in TeXstudio is the default one). Also, opening the compiled pdf outside TeXstudio with the Acrobat Reader shows the same issue. If I am using a DVI I don't know it; let me know how to see it and I answer back you.

Comment: Assuming there is more to your file than loading `graphicx` and the `document` environment, we are going to need a MWE. We'll probably also need some info from your log: with a short example that should be short enough to edit in.

Comment: @JosephWright Edited with a MWE.

Comment: Show also your log-file

Comment: The image you've uploaded to the file sharing service is _exactly_ the one you've shown in the question.

Comment: @JosephWright Ok! Sorry, I didn't realize it. I converted it form a `.svg` file (https://ufile.io/r4ift), so it seems the problem is in this step. Sorry again.

Comment: @SantiagoGil I think that makes this off-topic, or if you want to ask about including an SVG file a pretty heavy edit: at present LaTeX is doing what you are asking it to.

Comment: @JosephWright Heavy edit made.

Comment: @SantiagoGil Not really enough! Two issues: first, if you want to ask 'how do I include an SVG in a LaTeX document' then the question doesn't really say that at the moment. Second, the SVG image you link to is _still_ the same as the version in the question. Somewhere prior to the involvement of TeX at all something is going wrong, but we really can't help as things stand.

Comment: The is a package specifically for converting SVGs: see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122871/include-svg-images-with-the-svg-package.

Comment: @JosephWright As you commented, the SVG image is still the same wrong image. I found the problem, if someone reaches this comment. I created the image with draw.io, which has an open issue with formatted text exported to svg (https://support.draw.io/questions/1671290/why-does-the-text-of-svg-export-sometimes-not-display-correctly-in-ie-and-some-svg-editors)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is due to the nature of export from a non-TeX tool.