# Svg files do not work in Beamer

Tags: beamer, svg

I am building a beamer for a project, where i want some svg images. i have included 2 svg files and they work fine, but when i insert more they will not work.

```
\begin{frame}{Cooling demand}{Weight factor graph}

   \begin{figure}
       \centering
       \includesvg[width=\linewidth,pretex=\relscale{0.6}]{AAUgraphics/Weightfactorgraf.svg}
       \caption{weight factor graph for temperature gain from solar irradiation}
       \label{fig:my_label}
   \end{figure}

\end{frame}
```

this work fine for the first 2.

i use inkscape to convert into svg, and i have tried to convert into pdf_tex ass seen below:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\def\svgwidth{\columnwidth}
\input{image.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}
```

hope someone can help. Thanks

Comment: It seems you should not use an extension in `\includesvg` https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129854/141947