# Can I trim an SVG in LaTeX Code?

Tags: input, svg, trimbox

I want to trim my figure in LaTeX code. Unfortunately, it is an SVG figure, so I import it with:

```
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{0.8\columnwidth}
    \input{MessAbsch.eps_tex}  
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:measRanEst}
    \end{figure}
```

For normal `\includegraphics` you can use: `trim=1cm 2cm 3cm 4cm`, is there an equivalent for the  `\input` macro?

Comment: When importing SVG's I would generally advise you to use the svg package and using the \includesvg command. Here, you can add several parameters for the display of your SVG. Unfortunately I could not find an option to trim the images in the documentation. Is there a specific reason to why you cannot trim your image directly in inkscape?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122871/108724

Answer (score 3):

For importing SVG drawings, it is better to use the [`svg`](https://ctan.org/pkg/svg) package than to manually `\input` them. (See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523685/48973) for details on how to set it up.) This package does not provide a `trim` option, but the [`adjustbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package lets you trim (and clip) anything just like with `\includegraphics`.

So, after loading the packages

```latex
\usepackage[inkscapearea=page]{svg}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
```

you can trim your drawing

```latex
\adjustbox{trim=1cm 2cm 3cm 4cm}{%
  \includesvg{MessAbsch}%
}
```

Note that `\includegraphics` always trims first and scales after, but with `adjustbox` you will trim last. Thus, if you want your final drawing to have a width of `6cm`, you will have to include it too large before trimming.

```latex
\adjustbox{trim=1cm 2cm 3cm 4cm}{%
  \includesvg[width=9cm]{MessAbsch}%
}
```

---

This approach also works with `\input`, of course, but using `svg` comes with several advantages that make using it worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

I generally draw on Google slides and download the SVG files. I tried `\adjustbox` method mentioned by schtandard. It didn't work as expected.

Initially, i wanted to crop out the shaded area

[image]

I used

```
\lipsum[2-2]
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \adjustbox{trim=1cm 2cm 3cm 4cm}{
        \frame{\includesvg[width=0.90\textwidth]{Diagrams4.svg}}
    }
    \caption{\textbf{Overall ------------------------}}
    \label{fig:arch}
    \centering
\end{figure}
```

Result was as follows

[image]

I started reading the code of SVG files and found a way to manually crop SVG files. The following image illustrates my findings. You can imagine that robot is holding a knife.

[image]

A major drawback in above approach is that one has to try different values manually to get the perfect cropping window. I discovered a simpler way. We can simply crop SVG files using Libre Draw.

Insert image --> Crop --> Export as SVG

Result was as follows:

[image]