# Simple way to include .svg images

Tags: svg

I come to your rescue because I screwed up the only reference I had of an SVG file that I had successfully included in a document (somehow copied the file and it got deleted. Pretty sure I did not "Ctrl+X"d it). the code was really simple and something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{my_file.svg}
    \caption{some caption}
    \label{fig:X}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I'm pretty sure I used `\includegraphics`, but I could be wrong. Does anyone have a clue how to simply include an SVG file that looks very much like this example, but actually works? Thank you so much in advance for ending this rage of mine for having lost something I spent a few days trying to figure out!

Comment: use `\includesvg`  from the `svg` package, or use any external svg reader and export the image as pdf then use `\includegraphics` with that

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122871/include-svg-images-with-the-svg-package is related