# How to get a file's "date modified" string when including graphics?

Tags: graphics, external-files, import

I am working on my thesis, and want to have the date corresponding to when each figure was generated included in it's caption.

Currently I manually update the caption when I update the figure.

I am wondering if there is a LaTeX package or equivalent that I can use (with texmaker) to access the file information so that this field is generated automatically?

Comment: ahead of an answer, you might like to take a look at the code in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148361/28808).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there's a package for you: [filemod](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/filemod).

You should only need `\usepackage{filemod}` and `\filemodprintdate{〈filename〉}`

To adjust the formatting, you can use [datetime](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/datetime) as described in the filemod manual.

Both these packages appear to have been written by regulars here