# File SVG not found in windows texstudio

Tags: errors, texstudio, windows, svg

I was using latex for a while on Linux and I was using SVG. I remember it was a very hard time to fix the errors specially the one saying

> File "./somesvg" not found

Now, installed TeXStudio and latest version of InkScape, MikTex and required packages.

Making a simple test tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }     %%%% file path here
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includesvg[width=140mm]{samplecar}  %%%%%%%%%% error here
\caption{aaaaaaa}
\label{fig:aaaaaaaa}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Creating a folder called `images` and putting a file inside it called `samplecar.svg`.

I am getting error:

> File `./samplecar' not found. \includesvg[width=140mm]{samplecar}

Even copying `samplecar.svg` in the same path with `.tex` file does not help.

Where am I making mistake?

Please avoid linking to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/how-to-include-svg-diagrams-in-latex) as it does not help me.

Comment: Please tell us why [How to include SVG diagrams in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2099/5764) does not help you? Note that the linked post mentions you could convert SVG to PDF using Inkscape, rather than including it directly.

Comment: @Werner in Linux I could include SVG files directly and I want to do the same thing in windows. When I switch between my operating systems, the file must be compiled in the same way.

Comment: You cannot include the SVG directly. On Linux, you were converting the files and you must do the same on Windows. It may have looked as if you included them directly because the conversion was done automatically, but the images were converted or you'd not have been able to use them at all. Given that, I assume you want something like [this setup](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74693/). Have you installed all of the necessary programmes? (Note that you need ImageMagick for conversion and `pdftops`.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE, by the way!

Comment: @crf, I did not have `pdftops` however in the download [link](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html), there is no installation. Just a few exe files. I followed the instructions of that Tex SE answers and no difference in the result.

Comment: If you followed all of the instructions in the answer I linked to and it still doesn't work, make sure you have shell escape enabled. If it still doesn't work, I have no idea. I know zilch about Windows.

Comment: @cfr how to check if shell escape  works?

Comment: @zekri: You should check in TeXstudio's compilation sequence whether `--shell-escape` has been added.