# How to extract this SVG to LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, svg

I want to extract SVG picture for my Beamer presentation. 
I do the following but I get output in Fig. 1, based on the thread answer [How to include SVG diagrams in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2107/13173), without any errors/warnings

```
# https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2107/13173
inkscape -D -z --file=image.svg --export-pdf=image.pdf --export-latex
```

Input is [Wiki Ebola SVG picture](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a5/Filovirus_phylogenetic_tree.svg).

Fig. 1 Output from the command where all textual content is missing

[image]

OS: Debian 8.7
Inkscape: Inkscape 0.48.5 r10040 (Oct  7 2014)

Comment: The LaTeX/text is in the generated `image.pdf_tex` file. You have to include it into your document with `\input{image.pdf_tex}`

Comment: If maintain standard LaTeX font sizes and font type is not a must, is just safer and easier save it as PDF only (not pdf+LaTeX) and include the graphics  just as  JPG and PNG images. Otherwise, using xelatex or lualatex there are not problem to use the same font in the .svg and .tex files, so I guess that the issue will be only take care of the font size and the size of the SVG file, to avoid scaling in LaTeX.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are two ways to include an `.svg` image into `LaTeX`, there might be more possibilities of course.

The first one is the usage of the exporting figure to `.pdf` and `.pdf_tex`, where the second file contains the text (LaTeX) content.

Use `\usepackage{graphicx}` and `\input{image.pdf_tex}` then.

The easier way is `\usepackage{svg}` and `\includesvg`. This does the conversion internally, in this case, `graphicx` is loaded automatically.
Similar to `\includegraphics`, `\includesvg` allows for some options to configure the width and behaviour of the inclusion, important is `pretex`, for example. I refer to the manual for more information about the `svg` package.

However, in both ways the font size is too large, so use `\tiny` for example and optionally, some scale etc. option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}

{\tiny
\input{image.pdf_tex}}

\includesvg[pretex=\tiny]{img}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is the point of having such a confusing pdf output, the one in my body? - - Yes, I note that there is such a file as `pdf.tex`. Your approach seems to work.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: The `.pdf` file does contain the pure graphics only. I don't have developped `inkscape` ;-)

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 you explicitly told `inkscape` that you want two files by using the option `--export-latex`.

Comment: @samcarter Yes, but the content in those two files is not the same.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 The same content in both files would make zero sense. The whole point is to get all the text in latex format, which will ensure that the fonts etc. match the ones from your document. If this is too complicate, leave out the `--export-latex` option and you will simply get one image to include.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영, as you seem (from your the comments on this answer) to want a simple file structure, at the expense of losing font-matching, [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148361/28808) to the question you linked might help, as might the link in it