# pdf_tex file not found error using inkscape generated pdf + pdf_tex files and svg package

Tags: pdf, svg, inkscape

I am trying include an Inkscape generated pdf image, with text to be interpreted by LaTeX, into a LaTeX document.

When I keep the image files in the same folder as the tex file it works, but I would like to have my images in a subfolder `img`.

I've seen multiple instructions on how to accomplish this, but the mostly accepted way to do this seems to be to use the `svg` package by `\includepackage{svg}`, tel LaTeX where to look for files/images using `\svgpath{{img/}}` and insert the image into the document using `\input{example.pdf_tex}`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{svg}
\svgpath{{img/}}

\begin{document}
    \input{example.pdf_tex}
\end{document}
```

This is also the way as described in the [documentation of the `svg` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/svg/doc/svg.pdf)

However, when I do so, latex is not able to find the file and I get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `example.pdf_tex' not found.
```

Now, there are alternative ways to accomplish what I want to do. For instance to include `\graphicspath{{img/}}` or to use the `import` package with the command `\import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}`. I've also tried these commands using an absolute path.

Would anyone have an idea what is wrong?

Comment: What happens if you drop the `\svgpath... ` part and use `\input{img/example.pdf_tex} `?

Comment: @Rasmus thank you for your suggestion, it didn't solve it completely but did get me a step closer to the solution. Using your suggestion latex knows to find the pdf_tex file. It turned out, that it couldn't find the corresponding pdf file. This then could be solved by including ```\graphicspath{{img/}}``` to the preamble. Strange, but it now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the way to include `svg` files using the package of the same name is using the command `\includesvg` (as a pendant to `\includegraphics` for normal graphic inclusion). The argument of this command should point to the `svg` file (*not* the `pdf_tex` file) and you can tell LaTeX where to look for this file using the `\svgpath` macro (as a pentant to `\graphicspath`). LaTeX will then automatically call Inkscape to create the `pdf` and `pdf_tex` file (provided they are outdated or don't exist) and include them.

So, your MWE should read

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inkscapearea=page]{svg}
\svgpath{{img/}}

\begin{document}

\includesvg{example}

\end{document}
```

where `example.svg` is located in the `img/` subfolder.
(I included the `inkscapearea=page` option because I think that is what most people want.)

---

In order for this to work, you need to run LaTeX with shell escape enabled and have Inkscape in the system path variable. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523685/48973) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the suggestion Rasmus made in the comment to my original question. As it needed one additional step, I give the full solution here.

The problem is solved by telling LaTeX the location of the pdf_tex file at the moment it is included in the document by `\input{img/example.pdf_tex}`. Telling LaTeX where the corresponding pdf file can be found can be done by adding `\graphicspath{{img/}}` to the preamble. This tells LaTeX to search this folder for images.

Note that adding `\svgpath{{img/}}` in the preamble instead of `\graphicspath{{img/}}` doesn't work, it will raise the compiling error/ warning `` LaTeX Warning: File `example.pdf' not found ``. This is true for me and I'm using the TeX Live 2019 distribution.

The following thus works:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{svg}
\graphicspath{{img/}}

\begin{document}
    \input{img/example.pdf_tex}
\end{document}
```

Hope this will be useful for someone else as well.

Comment: You aren't actually using the svg package at all. If you remove the `\usepackage{svg}`, your document will show the same behavior. See my answer for how to properly use the package.

Comment: When I comment out the ```\usepackage{svg}``` I get an error ```! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \graphicspath
                 {{img/}}
?```
So it seems that LaTeX needs the svg package for *something* at least. But thank you very much for your answer as well, I haven't looked into calling Inkscape at LaTeX compile time. It looks like a better way to go.

Comment: You need to load `graphicx` (which is one of the packages `svg` loads in the background).