# Exporting pictures from InkScape to LaTeX

Tags: inkscape

I'd like to use some figures made with InkScape in my PhD thesis. What is the best export option for LaTeX?

1. Save as .pdf / .eps / .ps and attach the generated .tex file to my document. There was a problem (I did some research - I can't fix it) Latex doesn't recognize the text.

`\ put (0.07383757.0.37217584) {\ color [rgb] {1,1,1} \ makebox (0,0) [lt] {\ lineheight {1.25} \ smash {\ begin {tabular} [t] {l} d $ d $ \ end {tabular}}}}%`

Maybe there is a way to change that?

2. Export as .png. The resolution of the diagram is unacceptable.

I don't have much time to learn Ti*k*Z but my figures are mostly simple diagrams, not sure it's worth learning.

Comment: Have you checked out the [svg package](https://ctan.org/pkg/svg?lang=en)? But I'm not sure I understand the problem you're having with the first option: exactly how are you exporting to PDF from inkscape? Do you not want just to embed the text in the PDF?

Comment: @frabjous save as copy -> .pdf -> checked: PDF + LaTeX: Omit text in PDF and create LaTeX file. and I use ````\input{name.pdf_tex}``` in figure

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523685/38481

Comment: @Chey people use that method especially in order to have the text excluded so the text is recreated in the LaTeX with a font matching the document. If you want the text just as it is in Inkscape, you can export as a "normal" PDF with File > Export > Single Image > Choose PDF at the bottom, click export. But I'm glad the SVG package worked for you.

Comment: package `svg` also provides option `inkscapelatex=false` to leave text as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks to @frabjous I found package: `svg` and [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/how-to-include-svg-diagrams-in-latex/523685#523685)

Now it's work

Comment: Would be nice if you could add a before/after comparision to your answer, e.g. by code and/or screenshots.

Comment: I was using tex export file from inkscape and use \include{}. Now with svg package and TexText I can perform good quality figures