# Why SVG insertion is different from the source file?

Tags: overleaf, svg

I would like to insert this svg file with its style:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{svg}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.5}{\includesvg{./Test.svg}}
        \caption{Test}
        \label{fig:Test}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

I don't understand why the svg package from latex modify my source file without specification.

Comment: Is this any intention to use `\scalebox...`?

Comment: @GowriSaro, i tried without `\scalebox` but same result

Comment: Did you try using the `graphicx` package and `\includegraphics` as an alternative to `svg` and `\includesvg` ? Does the same (wrong) conversion occur when compiling the code?

Comment: package `svg` enables LaTeX to typeset any text within the svg (as documented). If this is not desired, you could just use `\includesvg[inkscapelatex=false]{./Test.svg}` And instead using `\scalebox` I would recommend to use `\includesvg[scale=0.5,inkscapelatex=false]{./Test.svg}` instead.

Comment: @alchemist I didn't use `graphix`

Comment: @mrpiggi thanks but I don't get the expected result. I have "-" instead of "-->"and the underlining is missing.

Comment: Well, then you would have to provide the svg file itself

Comment: @mrpiggi how please?

Comment: Well, you could just open your svg file with any text editor and post the content right here.

Comment: What you do only have sense if you want the text of the image replaced by LaTeX text to use the same font size and type that in the rest of the document. So the text size of the original image  should match the LaTeX font size, not in the opposite way. If you want the fonts exactly as showed in Inkscape, is just simpler to save your SVG image as PDF (without making a file LaTeX file for text !)  and use `\includegraphics` like you do with PNG or JPG images.

Answer (score 5):

With package `svg` there are two different approaches regarding the use of fonts:

#### LaTeX in control

This is the default setting. Any formatting of the fonts in the SVG file is ignored and all text is typeset by LaTeX. Adjustments to the font regarding family, size, weight, shape etc. must be made in LaTeX style directly in the SVG file, using commands such as `\small`, `\huge` or `\textbf{...}` in text fields accordingly.

#### Inkscape in control

With `inkscapelatex=false`, LaTeX is disabled for processing text in the SVG file. This can be set for all processed SVG files with `\svgsetup{inkscapelatex=false}` or individually for certain files by using `\includesvg[inkscapelatex=false,...]{...}` as needed. In this case, all font formatting remains as it is in the SVG file. This also means, math expressions like `$a+b=c$` aren't processed as well and there maybe raises the need to adjust font face, type etc. according to the document if desired.

###### Note

Regardless of the approach chosen, I recommend to create the SVG graphic preferably in the same size as it should appear in the final output and, if necessary, scaling it only minimally to avoid distorting the chosen fonts in particular.