# Including SVG in TexStudio (texlive)

Tags: texlive, texstudio, windows, svg, inkscape

I got some problems moving from Overleaf to local compilers.

Earlier, in Overleaf, I could just use

```
\usepackage{svg}
...
\hspace*{0.2\textwidth} \includesvg[width=0.5\textwidth]{optic}
```

But now, in TeXStudio with TeXLive I have some errors with it:

```
Package svg Error: File `optic_svg-tex.pdf_tex' is missing. ...h} \includesvg[width=0.5\textwidth]{optic}
You didn't enable `shell escape' (or `write18')(svg) so it wasn't possible to launch the Inkscape export(svg) for `optic.svg'
```

I didn't find anything working correctly on forums.
I set something in  TeXStudio and in Windows, but it doesn't work.

[image: Windows PATH looks like this:]

[image: In TeXStudio I set these commands for LuaLaTeX:]

Can anybody make full guide how to use `\includesvg` in TeXStudio? I also tried MiKTex, the problem was the same.

Comment: You need to compile with `shell-escape` enabled. Can you show a screenshot of your texstudio `preferences->Commands`?

Comment: I reset TeXStudio settings to defaults, and now it looks like that (default compiler-pdflatex) https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhHFa.jpg

Comment: Thanks! Just as a test: can you try with `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstop -shell-escape %.tex`?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VJcp.png

It doesn't continue compilating after these logs

Comment: (sorry, there was a typo in my previous comment, it should have read `-interaction=nonstopmode`)

Comment: The new error message looks like to come from inkscape. Can you share your `.svg` file so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Can you try the MWE from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/523685/48973)? If that works, there's probably something wrong with your SVG file. If it doesn't work, there's something wrong with your setup (though it looks good from your screenshots).

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you so much, everything is working correctly now

Comment: @AntoineRuss Glad to hear! Have fun with texstudio!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz could you explain me please, what does `-interaction=nonstopmode` means?

Comment: @AntoineRuss It means that latex won't stop at error messages

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved in comments. The full guide:

1. Install TeXLive and TexStudio
2. Install InkScape and put it in windows PATH:
   Instruction: https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/
   In path settings add this line:`C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin`

[image: Like this:]

3. In TeXStudio preferences>>commands set `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex` in this string:

[image: PdfLaTeX(mb in another compilers it also could work)]

And set PdfLaTeX as default compiler. After that everything will work correctly, I hope