# Processing document with SVGs for submission to arXiv

Tags: graphics, svg, arxiv

I use the `svg` package in Overleaf, with the pdfLaTeX compiler, to include SVGs in my document. I am preparing to upload to arXiv, but images have to be JPEGs, PNGs, or PDFs.

One benefit of using the `svg` package is that I can very easily include math equations (with commands) in the SVG, which the compiler typesets nicely. For example, I could include a file containing `<text>Math: $frac{1}{3}$</text>`, and I don't want to lose this functionality if possible. What is the simplest way to convert my document and figures so that it looks the same as when Overleaf compiles it? I think Overleaf uses Inkscape, so doing something like [this](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf) is a worst-case option.

Comment: Your "worst case" option is what `svg` package does under the hood; `svg` just automates the process. See also the extensive discussion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2099/119).

Comment: the svg package will have called inksckape to make pdf of each svg which will be in your overleaf project generated files cache. you can simply save them and include them directly instead of the svg

Comment: There is an additional package called `svg-extract` which can be used to extract (and convert) all files included with `\includesvg` to standalone files.

Answer (score 2):

The `svg` package calls Inkscape to convert your *.svg* files into a *.pdf* file and a *.pdf_tex* file. By default, they are stored in a folder called `svg-inkscape`. When those files are not older than the *.svg* file, they are included without attempting to re-convert the *.svg* file, so typesetting without Inkscape is no problem.

If you are submitting to a journal that requires all figures to be submitted individually as they appear in the document (i.e. with the typeset text), the package `svg-extract` can help you with that. Just load it and the package will store a typeset version of each included *.svg* file in a folder `svg-extract`.

If you are working on Overleaf, you can download the files from `svg-inkscape` from the file cache accessible at the bottom of the log view, as described [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/View_generated_files). Only individual file downloads seem to be supported. `svg-extract` is currently not supported by Overleaf.